# How to remove camera permission from expo-image-picker?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm in expo manage workflow. I use expo-image-picker package to take a photo with camera and use it in my app. The custom store that I've uploaded my app rejected it. It says "Use Intents and remove camera permission from Android Manifest".

I've tried to remove android.permission.CAMERA from Image Picker Manifest file and save it with patch-package but the button that calls launchCameraAsync() does not work any more.
I've also tried using {"blockedPermissions": ["android.permission.Camera"]} in app.json but the button doesn't work again.

Is there any solution to remove camera permission from Manifest, or are there any other camera libraries to use?

Answer (score 0):

In app.json set `expo.android.permissions: ['CAMERA']`

Comment: I want to remove camera permission completely and use camera without camera permission (using Intents)

Comment: then try to leave this array empty

Comment: What is that for? Without camera permission expo-image-picker won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

1. Remove the `android.permission.CAMERA` permission from the Manifest.
2. Make sure your Expo SDK version is at least 43.0.0.
3. Use **launchImageLibraryAsync()** instead of **launchCameraAsync()** from expo-image-picker.
4. Use **requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()** to test and handle the permission request for accessing the device's media library.

In your case it may be the 3rd point that causing the issue.

Comment: But I need camera in my app. The store says use Intents instead, which is related to native Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the CAMERA permission your app will effectively not be able to take photos since the `expo-image-picker` plugin [requires](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#permissions) the CAMERA permission.

The [Camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#android) plugin also requires the CAMERA permission so you would run into the same issue.

What the store is telling you with "*Use Intents and remove camera permission from Android Manifest*" is that they do not accept apps that require the CAMERA permission. In native Android there is another option to take pictures without using any permissions by creating an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/camera-intents), this will allow the user to use whichever Camera app they choose to take the picture and return the data to the app.

You could try using the [`expo-intent-launcher`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/) plugin to create an intent using the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action, you will have to pass the uri where you want the image to be stored in `IntentLauncherParams.data` so you can retrieve the image later. Since there is no such feature in iOS this solution will only work in Android, as shown in expo-intent-launcher's [Platform Compatibility](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/#platform-compatibility).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But I can't find ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in ActivityAction of expo-intent-launcher.